# How to change the direction of a fill transition in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm struggling to fine out if its possible to control the direction of a fill transition with CSS.

I'm using an infinity loop inline SVG as an icon I would like to animate.

Basically I'd like the icon to change color when hovered over, but start a the bottom middle and follow the flow of the infinity loop.

Heres a GIF that is very similar to the effect I'd like to achieve.

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/117549/screenshots/1372400/loop.gif

Any help or advice appreciated!

Comment: It looks like possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934749/on-hover-fill-element-from-center-outwards

Comment: This didn't help me :/

Comment: Can you show us your SVG markup?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SVG path, then one possible solution is to use [stroke-dasharray](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) and [stroke-dashoffset](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/).

Can you post a fiddle of what you have done until now?

Comment: I just have the SVG markup at the moment and have it scaled down, in the markup is does have one path with the class "st0"

Comment: We can't help without looking at the markup. Post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your svg markup, so we can have a look at the problem

Comment: Here's a fiddle of the SVG markup, it's just scaled down with a hover effect changing the fill to the desired color. http://jsfiddle.net/37x2r9nt/1/

I'll like some how to get the fill to start at the bottom center points and follow the flow of the loop, if it's possible