# Fill element with slanted background on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, css-shapes

I'm trying to create an **CSS button hover effect**. But I didn't manage to fill the element with a slanted shape.

How the hover effect was planned:

[image: Fill button with slanted shape on hover]

Screenshot 1: How it looks actually.

Screenshot 2: How I want the hover effect to look like with slanted side.

```css
.button_sliding_bg {
  color: #31302B;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 17px;
  margin: 25px;
  font-family: 'OpenSansBold', sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid #31302B;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #31302B;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}
.button_sliding_bg:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 0 #31302B;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button class="button_sliding_bg">Buttontext</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you are actually looking for the end state to fill the entire element with background color and not leave the gap. You could also do it with `linear-gradient` background images and transition their `background-size` and `background-position` like in the below snippet.

One disadvantage of using `linear-gradient` over pseudo-elements or transforms is that the browser support is lower but it doesn't need extra pseudo-elements and so can leave them spare for other use.

```css
.button_sliding_bg {
  color: #31302B;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 17px;
  margin: 25px;
  font-family: 'OpenSansBold', sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid #31302B;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #31302B 50%, transparent 51%);
  background-size: 100px 100px; /* some initial size to get the slanted appearance */
  background-position: -50px -50px; /* negative positioning to hide it initially */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}
.button_sliding_bg:hover {
  background-size: 200% 200%; /* 200% because gradient is colored only for 50% */
  background-position: 0px 0px; /* bring it fully into view */
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<button class="button_sliding_bg">Buttontext</button>
<button class="button_sliding_bg">Button text lengthy</button>
<button class="button_sliding_bg">Button text <br> with line break</button>
<button class="button_sliding_bg">Button text <br> with <br> multiple <br> line <br>breaks</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the technique described in this answer : [Fill element from center on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934749/fill-element-from-center-on-hover/23935736#23935736) and skew the pseudo element so it fills the button with a slant :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 70px;
  border: 5px solid #B17461;
  color: #B17461;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  transition: color .5s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 130%; height: 100%;
  background: #B17461;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin:0 0 ;
  transform:translateX(-100%) skewX(-45deg);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
div:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
div:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(0) skewX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>BUTTON</div>
```

Don't forget to add vendor prefixes for browser support (see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) for more info).

Answer (score 2):

You can use css `:after`.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zz9oqofk/1/)

```css
.button_sliding_bg {
    color: #31302B;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 12px 17px;
    margin: 25px;
    font-family:'OpenSansBold', sans-serif;
    border: 3px solid #31302B;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #31302B;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
    transition: all ease 0.8s;
    position: relative;
}
.button_sliding_bg:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 200px 0 0 0 #31302B;
    color: #FFF;
}
.button_sliding_bg:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 0 0;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 32px 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
    transition: all ease 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<button class="button_sliding_bg">Buttontext</button>
```