# Make Hover gradient animation in a div with 45 deg angle?

Tags: css, background, hover, gradient

I am trying to make a hover effect in a div. When I hover over the div background gradient will transform by 45 deg, But the problem I am facing is I can not make it 0 to 100% means I want to show the gray color normally. when I will hover the the green color will show gradually with 45 deg. How can I do that?

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.skillsDouble {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.skillsDouble li {
    width:200px;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background: #ff3232;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,  green 50%, grey 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all .5s ease;
  height:100px;
}
.skillsDouble li:hover {
    background-position:left bottom;
}
.skillsDouble li a {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="skillsDouble">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Automation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">TDD</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the question fully but are you looking for something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869410/fill-element-with-slanted-background-on-hover/33871088#33871088? Maybe an image of the hover state and the un-hovered state could help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `background-size: 200% 100%;` if you set it to `background-size: 300% 100%;` it should be the behavior you are looking for.