# Animation hover on button in css to expand background color in horizontal and when leave coming strangulate in the center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make same animated effect when hover on button.
First of all I want when hover on button to expand background color black  in horizontal of button I belive might I shoud use any transation property?
Secondly When leave mouse hover  on button background color  strangulate like
border-radius in the center of the button.

I have did until now  to created a class btn and put same styles in tag head like code below.
But when I leave mouse over  on button background-color dont't strangulate in the center as I mentiod before.

```css
<style>
    body {
        background: #2ecc71;
        font-size: 62.5%;
    }
    
    .container {
        padding: 2em;
    }
    /* GENERAL BUTTON STYLING */
    
    button,
    button::after {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    
    button {
        background: none;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.6em;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 1em auto;
        padding: 2em 6em;
        position: relative;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    button::before,
    button::after {
        background: black;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    button:hover {
        color: #2ecc71;
    }
    
    .btn-3::after {
        height: 0;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: 0;
    }
    
    .btn-3:hover:after {
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* BUTTON 4 */
</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn-3">Button 3</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

This is exactly what I want to create for button hover by the design UI/UX:[enter link description here](https://www.figma.com/proto/kwnH9NnM6eZO9eGAjEpEaG/Passport-Site-(Copy)?node-id=10%3A185&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=10%3A185) When hover display background-color: horizontal, after leave mouse hover coming background color strangulate in the center on the button.

By the Figma, I am talking for this button:[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Do you have an example? I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please read this and click: when said enter link description here.  This is exactly what I want to create for button hover by the design UI/UX:enter link description here When hover display background-color: horizontal, after leave mouse hover coming background color strangulate in the center on the button

Comment: Marshall I have explained in the first of description.

Comment: It's not a public figma

Comment: <iframe style="border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);" width="800" height="450" src="https://www.figma.com/embed?embed_host=share&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.figma.com%2Fproto%2FkwnH9NnM6eZO9eGAjEpEaG%2FPassport-Site-(Copy)%3Fnode-id%3D10%253A185%26scaling%3Dmin-zoom%26page-id%3D0%253A1%26starting-point-node-id%3D10%253A185" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Please you can try agin in the last my comment click  link figma.

Comment: Doesn't work, you need to change the permissions of the figma document so it's public.

Comment: Please you can try agin in the last my comment click link figma , or click link above

Comment: This is quite hard, I found this that might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934749/fill-element-from-center-on-hover

Comment: I have an example that you have send me. Thanks a lot